# When Will Azure ADLS Gen 2 SDK Be Released?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

It seems like the SDKs for Data Lake Storage Gen2 are not available now. Are there other ways / workarounds?

This seems like a questions many others also have: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/22913

Any news about an SDK for gen2 datalake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-known-issues#all-other-features-and-tools) about ADLS GEN2:

> You can use Data Lake Storage Gen2 REST APIs, but APIs in other Blob
>   SDKs such as the .NET, Java, Python SDKs are not yet available.

So,you could use it by REST API, there are some threads for you reference:

1.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45be0931-379d-4252-9d20-164261cc64c5/error-while-calling-adls-gen-2-rest-api-to-create-file?forum=AzureDataLake

2.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/dc102604-bdb7-47be-8de4-dc47a42e31a4/azure-data-lake-gen2-rest-api?forum=AzureDataLake

To push the progress of sdk, you could submit your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback?query=azure%20data%20lake%20sdk) so that azure team will leave the latest comments.